# How should I encrypt App.config for an Azure WebJob?

Tags: c#, azure, encryption, ssl-certificate, azure-webjobs

I'm building an Azure Website-based solution that needs to periodically contact a Service Bus relay endpoint in the background. My planned design approach was to use an Azure WebJob as the execution engine for this background task -- I would store my Service Bus connection string with shared secret credentials in App.config, encrypt it using the Pkcs12ProtectedConfigurationProvider with my site's custom SSL certificate, and everything would work perfectly!

The only problem is, it appears that WebJobs are not able to access the certificates for their containing Websites. The code for my WebJob can be very simple (but note that the appSettings section of App.config is encrypted):

```
public static void Main()
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"];
    Console.WriteLine(connectionString);
}
```

If I import the site's certificate on my local machine and run the WebJob executable there, everything works as expected. But when I upload the ZIP file with my binaries and .exe.config file into Azure, the job always fails with the below error.

```
[07/18/2014 22:53:24 > 621d84: ERR ] Unhandled Exception:
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Failed to decrypt using provider 'Pkcs12Provider'.
Error message from the provider: No certificate was found for thumbprint <My Certificate's Thumbprint>
(C:\DWASFiles\Sites\<My Site Name>\Temp\jobs\triggered\<My Job Name>\hzcfdtn5.f22\WebJob.exe.Config line
XX) ---> System.ApplicationException: No certificate was found for thumbprint <My Certificate's Thumbprint>
```

Am I correct in surmising that a WebJob can't access the corresponding Website's certificate store? This would make it pretty much impossible to use the Pkcs12 provider to encrypt my WebJob's secrets -- is there a better option available? Or is a WebJob simply the wrong tool for this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure WebSites, AFAIK, cannot use custom certificates.

However, you can put the connection strings in the connection strings section of your website in the Azure Portal. Here are details on how to read it afterwards: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/07/17/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/

While the above will not solve the encryption problem, it would at least remove the CS from AppConfig. That's what we do with the Service Bus connection string for Azure WebJobs SDK http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/18/announcing-the-0-3-0-beta-preview-of-microsoft-azure-webjobs-sdk/

A webjobs seems to be the right tool for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Oh wow, somehow it never occurred to me to try the app settings and connection strings in the portal for a WebJob; I'd assumed they'd only work for the site itself. But it works great, so I'd say that answers the question. However, I should also note that it definitely _is_ possible to upload custom SSL certificates for an Azure Website (but it should not be necessary unless you are using a custom domain). Source: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/